# What is the definition of outer and inner in ARMv7?

Tags: architecture, arm

I'm reading ARMv7 architecture reference manual and there are the following keywords:

- outer cacheable
- inner cacheable
- outer sharable
- inner sharable

It looks like that outer/inner cacheable means that a region of memory can be cached in L1 (inner) or L2 (outer).

What I don't understand is the sharability.

According to the manual, it says inner is sharable inside a cluster and outer is sharable among clusters.

Here, what does cluster mean? It looks like a group of cores, but I'm failed to find exact reference about these.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You should read more at [Cortex A Series programmer's guide](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.den0013d/index.html), chapter `10.7 Memory Attributes` (free book from arm) however, here is an excerpt:

> *cluster*: a multiple core Cortex-A15 processor and a multiple core Cortex-A7 processor.

Chapter 9 also talks about caches, which might clarify terms for you even further.
From another [ARM blog post](http://community.arm.com/groups/processors/blog/2014/02/19/new-version-of-the-cortex-a-series-programmers-guide-available):

> You will also notice that what we call the devices has changed. The
>   terms CPU and processor were ambiguous so:
>
> - **Processor** now only refers to the marketed device, such as the
>     Cortex®-A15 processor,
> - **Core** refers to a single implementation of a processor. This was sometimes called a CPU in the past.
> - **Clusters** are groups of multiple cores sharing an L2 cache
> - A big.LITTLE system typically refers to two clusters of cores, although it could be a single big core and a cluster of several LITTLE
>     cores.

Answer (score -2):

"Inner" and "Outer" are "shareability domains". Though it's not guaranteed, generally "Inner" is the L1 cache and "Outer" is the L2 cache.